# JQGRID- Display Inline message on form edit window

Tags: jqgrid

When a record being edited using form edit. Please advise how to display a message inline
"Record cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a an "delete" option

```
$("#gGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagergGrid',{add:true,edit:true,del:false,search:true}, //NAVIGATION BAR
        { }, // edit options 
        { }, // add options 
        {msg: "Record cannot be deleted"}, //del options
        { 
        } // search options

        );
```

It is explained [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) in detail